# How to auto adjust the font size of a spinner based on its longest value in android

Tags: android, spinner, textview

I have a spinner in which I want to display several names. 
I get the names based on a sqlite query. How I can reduce font size based on the length of the longest name? Shall I use and check with

```
textView.getText().length()  ?
```

Comment: do need full names in spinner ? if not use `android:singleLine=true` in spinner inflated text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive:

1. Find longest string.
2. Measure TextView Max size.
3. Measure
   text to fit inside TextView. (Using TextPaint, that provides measure text methods.)

You just need to figure out algorithm. Could be something like this.

```
size = TextView.getWidth();
paint = new TextPaint();
paint.setTextSize(SOME_BIG_NUMBER);
while(true){
   if (paint.measureText(longest_text) < size){
       break;
   } else {
       paint.setTextSize(paint.getTextSize() -1f);
   }
}
result size = paint.getTextSize();
```

Another approach could be using AutoResizeTextView. After setting data, just go thru all AutoResizeTextViews, find minimum, then set it to all TextViews. But it's extremely expensive and user will notice drawing.

```
public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {

private interface SizeTester {
    /**
     * @param suggestedSize Size of text to be tested
     * @param availableSpace available space in which text must fit
     *
     * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
     * text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
     * otherwise
     */
    public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
}

private RectF mTextRect = new RectF();

private RectF mAvailableSpaceRect;

private SparseIntArray mTextCachedSizes;

private TextPaint mPaint;

private float mMaxTextSize;

private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

private float mMinTextSize = 20;

private int mWidthLimit;

private Typeface mTypeFace;

private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;
private int mMaxLines;

private boolean mEnableSizeCache = true;
private boolean mInitiallized;

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = -1;
    for (String st : list) {
        index = index < st.length() ? st.length() :index;
    }

    TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
    paint.measureText(list.get(index));
}

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    mPaint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
    if (mTypeFace != null) {
        mPaint.setTypeface(mTypeFace);
    }
    mMaxTextSize = getTextSize();
    mAvailableSpaceRect = new RectF();
    mTextCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();
    if (mMaxLines == 0) {
        // no value was assigned during construction
        mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
    }
    mInitiallized = true;
}

@Override
public void setText(final CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);
    adjustTextSize(text.toString());
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    mMaxTextSize = size;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void setMaxLines(int maxlines) {
    super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
    mMaxLines = maxlines;
    reAdjust();
}

public int getMaxLines() {
    return mMaxLines;
}

@Override
public void setSingleLine() {
    super.setSingleLine();
    mMaxLines = 1;
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine) {
    super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
    if (singleLine) {
        mMaxLines = 1;
    } else {
        mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
    }
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
public void setLines(int lines) {
    super.setLines(lines);
    mMaxLines = lines;
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
    Context c = getContext();
    Resources r;

    if (c == null) {
        r = Resources.getSystem();
    } else {
        r = c.getResources();
    }
    mMaxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size,
        r.getDisplayMetrics());
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
    super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    mSpacingMult = mult;
    mSpacingAdd = add;
}

/**
 * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
 *
 * @param minTextSize
 */
public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
    mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
    reAdjust();
}

private void reAdjust() {
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

private void adjustTextSize(String string) {
    if (!mInitiallized) {
        return;
    }
    int startSize = (int) mMinTextSize;
    int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom()
        - getCompoundPaddingTop();
    mWidthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft()
        - getCompoundPaddingRight();
    if (mWidthLimit < 0) {
        mWidthLimit = 0;
    }
    mAvailableSpaceRect.right = mWidthLimit;
    mAvailableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;
    super.setTextSize(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
        efficientTextSizeSearch(startSize, (int) mMaxTextSize,
            mSizeTester, mAvailableSpaceRect));
}

private final SizeTester mSizeTester = new SizeTester() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSPace) {
        mPaint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);
        String text = getText().toString();
        boolean singleline = getMaxLines() == 1;
        if (singleline) {
            mTextRect.bottom = mPaint.getFontSpacing();
            mTextRect.right = mPaint.measureText(text);
        } else {
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, mPaint,
                mWidthLimit, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult,
                mSpacingAdd, true);
            // return early if we have more lines
            if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT
                && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines()) {
                return 1;
            }
            mTextRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();
            int maxWidth = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
                if (maxWidth < layout.getLineWidth(i)) {
                    maxWidth = (int) layout.getLineWidth(i);
                }
            }
            mTextRect.right = maxWidth;
        }

        mTextRect.offsetTo(0, 0);
        if (availableSPace
            .contains(mTextRect)) { // may be too small, don't worry we will find the best match
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (mTextRect.bottom < availableSPace.bottom
                && mTextRect.right > availableSPace.right) {
                // hack :O
                return -1;
            }
            // too big
            return 1;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Enables or disables size caching, enabling it will improve performance
 * where you are animating a value inside TextView. This stores the font
 * size against getText().length() Be careful though while enabling it as 0
 * takes more space than 1 on some fonts and so on.
 *
 * @param enable enable font size caching
 */
public void enableSizeCache(boolean enable) {
    mEnableSizeCache = enable;
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
}

private int efficientTextSizeSearch(int start, int end,
    SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace) {
    if (!mEnableSizeCache) {
        return binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
    }
    String text = getText().toString();
    int key = text == null ? 0 : text.length();
    int size = mTextCachedSizes.get(key);
    if (size != 0) {
        return size;
    }
    size = binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
    mTextCachedSizes.put(key, size);
    return size;
}

private static int binarySearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester,
    RectF availableSpace) {
    int lastBest = start;
    int lo = start;
    int hi = end - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    while (lo <= hi) {
        mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
        int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);
        if (midValCmp < 0) {
            lastBest = lo;
            lo = mid + 1;
        } else if (midValCmp > 0) {
            hi = mid - 1;
            lastBest = hi;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    // make sure to return last best
    // this is what should always be returned
    return lastBest;
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
    final int before, final int after) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
    reAdjust();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth,
    int oldheight) {
    mTextCachedSizes.clear();
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
    if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight) {
        reAdjust();
    }
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
    super.setTypeface(tf);
    mTypeFace = tf;
    if (mInitiallized) {
        mPaint.setTypeface(tf);
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        reAdjust();
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
    return TextView.class.getName();
}
}
```

Best approach is to combine these approaches. Find longest text. Simplify the AutoResizeTextView to only calculate textSize. Set this size to you textViews.